# How to bind ng-model to directive's scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i stcuked on binding ng-model which is inside directive's template html which is

```
<input type="file" ng-model="uimg" value="TEST"/>

<button ng-click="Upload(user,uimg)"
        class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
</button>
```

as you see i have a ng-model called "uimg" , but when i click button , function calls this code

here is the directive class which i wrote

export class CustomDirective implements ng.IDirective{

```
    public controller: any;
    public restrict: string;
    public templateUrl: string;
    public scope: Object;
    public link:ng.IDirectiveLinkFn;
    public transclude:boolean;

    constructor(restrict: string,
        scope: Object ,
        controller: any,
        templateUrl: string,
        link:any
    ) {

        this.restrict = restrict;
        this.controller = controller;
        this.templateUrl = templateUrl;
        this.scope = scope;
        this.link = link;
        this.transclude = true;

    }

}
```

and i register directive to the app.

```
app.directive("uploadKimlik",
() => new Application.Directive.CustomDirective("A",
    { user: "=",uimg:"=" },
    "",
    Application.Helper.Generic.GetPath() + "admin/GetHtml/?id=upload",
    (scope) => {
        scope.Upload=(u,i)=> {
            alert("u john");
            console.log(scope.user);
            console.log(i);
        };
    }));
```

first alert works and alerts "u john" 
second console.log(scope.user) works too but my ng-model which i created in directive returns undefined.

what is the wrong i could not understand.

any help will be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: You are not using the `u` parameter inside `Upload`. You are not showing how are you filling the `user` scope member when using the directive (you are not showing HTML code using the directive, but just the template of the directive)

Comment: whole code is so long thats why i did not write them. shortly i pass user value to the directives scope with html tag.<div upload-kimlik user="user" uimg=""></div> yes i did not use parameter "u"  i was testing that parameter if works when i pass object.

Comment: test whether the user you are passing is actually defined when you call the directive